# Laravel 4 + Iron: How to register a queue?

Tags: powershell, laravel, queue, laravel-4, iron

I have setup a free account and create a first project: queue_test
I have followed this tutorial: http://vimeo.com/64703617  by Taylor Otwell and create a simple app that uses queues.
I put that app on the server.
The point is: How can i push the queue?
How can i run this command:
php artisan queue:subscribe queue_test http://mydomain.com/queue/push
if normally i use powershell on localhost..
How can i run that command on the server?

Someone can clarify to me this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually in https://hud.iron.io/dashboard:

- Open the IronMQ (MQ button) for your project.
- Click the Queues tab
- Click on your queue name
- In the subscribers widget, add your url: `http://mydomain.com/queue/push`.

Comment: Sorry, where is the subscribers widget?
I see only the Real-time data and Historic data

Comment: Here: http://puu.sh/4zeC2.png. It's in the bottom of that page, if you got there. Those are the tabs you should see: http://puu.sh/4zeEJ.png.